# The field VersionData not queried in SOQL for ContentVersion sobject

Tags: apex, soql, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I queried the ContentVersion object by following soql, VersionData field is not retrieved in results.

```
SELECT Id, Title, VersionData, PathOnClient, ContentSize FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id=<Id>
```

This is the log of the SOQL result, only the `VersionData` field is missing.

```
ContentVersion:{Id=<id>, Title=ABC.jpg, PathOnClient=ABC.jpg, ContentSize=1234, FileType=JPG}
```

As per this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353993&type=1), we don't have a way to provide FLS for ContentVersion fields.
The class executing SOQL is defined as `without sharing`. The logged-in user has a Standard User profile. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you certain that log is for that SOQL? It displays `FileType`, yet that field isn't in the query either.

Comment: Yes, FileType is retrieved, even though it is not in SOQL.